# Re-writing code chunk using While loop

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, procedural-programming, infinite-loop

I can't seem to wrap my head around the syntax for how to rewrite this chunk of code I have using a while loop, and would appreciate some help. I'm going through a list and am grouping the values into clusters based off distance at different time steps. Now for *this particular time step*,since I know the number of groupings, so I was able to write the code as such, and store these five groups in `bFill` like so:

```
update = {215.747, 215.238, 213.231, 213.162, 212.202, 212.17, 211.369,211.341, 211.017, 210.873, 210.802, 210.649, 210.586, 210.484, 210.4, 210.32, 210.287, 210.198, 210.18, 210.048, 210.047, 210.01, 209.971, 209.958, 209.889, 209.846, 209.819, 209.815, 209.77, 209.754, 209.538, 209.498, 209.452, 209.296, 209.162, 209.136, 209.039, 209.015, 209.007, 208.935, 208.78, 208.671, 208.555, 208.51, 208.3, 208.169, 208.143, 137.806, 137.792, 137.68, 136.943, 136.324, 136.087, 135.653, 135.405, 135.31, 134.587, 132.697, 131.655, 131.253, 124.246, 123.571, 123.543, 123.357, 123.277, 123.079, 122.833, 122.53, 122.433, 122.377, 122.21, 122.192, 122.174, 122.109, 122.097, 121.866, 121.632, 121.619, 121.519, 121.51, 121.415, 121.392, 121.362, 121.303, 121.075, 121.048, 120.652, 120.602, 120.282, 120.209, 119.208, 119.08, 118.918, 118.843, 118.836, 118.655, 118.628, 118.481, 117.876, 117.574, -165.322, -165.584, -165.791, -166.015, -166.172, -166.33, -168.422, -168.681, -169.081, -169.347, -169.633, -170.288, -170.564, -170.79, -172.107, -172.116, -173.292, -173.563, -173.587, -174.051, -174.143, -174.261, -174.274, -174.346, -174.528, -174.978, -175.021, -175.079, -175.096, -175.14, -175.165, -175.295, -175.69,-175.802, -175.88, -175.909, -176.06, -176.177, -176.386, -176.464, -176.547, -176.55, -177.538, -178.261, -178.486, -210.531, -211.429,-211.476, -211.726, -211.752, -211.851, -211.886, -211.891, -212.046, -212.12, -212.327, -212.75, -212.873, -213.008, -213.154, -213.261, -213.275, -213.438, -213.682, -213.834, -213.921, -213.949, -213.98, -213.986, -214.185, -214.307, -214.389, -214.422, -214.763, -214.91,-215.697, -215.767, -215.799, -216.192, -216.203, -216.217, -216.236, -216.256, -216.412, -216.518, -216.796, -216.841, -216.873, -217.059, -217.2, -217.382, -217.454, -217.576, -217.655, -217.752, -218.143, -218.216, -218.301, -218.343, -224.348};
diam = 14.2535;
bFill = {};
branch = {};
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, update[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, list[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, list[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, list[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, list[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
```

Now for this code I would "know" that I'm done when `Length@update == 0`, which is the case in the last step, so I was thinking of trying to re-write it like so:

```
(* update and diam same as from previous *)
bFill = {};
branch = {};

While[Length@update > 0,
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, update[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
]
```

but this just ends up throwing out all sorts of errors, so clearly I'm not writing it correctly. In the end, I'm expecting `bFill` to look like so:

```
[In]:= bFill
[Out]:= {{215.747, 215.238, 213.231, 213.162, 212.202, 212.17, 211.369,211.341, 211.017, 210.873, 210.802, 210.649, 210.586, 210.484,210.4, 210.32, 210.287, 210.198, 210.18, 210.048, 210.047, 210.01,209.971, 209.958, 209.889, 209.846, 209.819, 209.815, 209.77,209.754, 209.538, 209.498, 209.452, 209.296, 209.162, 209.136,209.039, 209.015, 209.007, 208.935, 208.78, 208.671, 208.555,208.51, 208.3, 208.169, 208.143}, {137.806, 137.792, 137.68, 136.943, 136.324, 136.087, 135.653, 135.405, 135.31, 134.587, 132.697, 131.655, 131.253, 124.246, 123.571}, {123.543, 123.357,123.277, 123.079, 122.833, 122.53, 122.433, 122.377, 122.21, 122.192, 122.174, 122.109, 122.097, 121.866, 121.632, 121.619, 121.519, 121.51, 121.415, 121.392, 121.362, 121.303, 121.075, 121.048, 120.652, 120.602, 120.282, 120.209, 119.208, 119.08, 118.918, 118.843, 118.836, 118.655, 118.628, 118.481, 117.876,117.574}, {-165.322, -165.584, -165.791, -166.015, -166.172,-166.33, -168.422, -168.681, -169.081, -169.347, -169.633, -170.288, -170.564, -170.79, -172.107, -172.116, -173.292, -173.563, -173.587, -174.051, -174.143, -174.261, -174.274, -174.346, -174.528, -174.978, -175.021, -175.079, -175.096, -175.14, -175.165, -175.295, -175.69, -175.802, -175.88, -175.909, -176.06, -176.177, -176.386, -176.464, -176.547, -176.55, -177.538, -178.261, -178.486}}
```

I can't seem to make sense to myself how to re-write this in a recursive fashion, so any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I was just trying a simple `While` loop like so:

```
l = Table[1, 5];
n = 1;
While[
Length@l > 0, n = n*Length@l;
l = Delete[l, 1]
]
n
(* 120 *)
```

which works, just as a sanity check that I can indeed use the length of `update` as the condition for the `While` loop. I thought maybe with some moving things around it might work:

```
While[
Length@update > 0, 
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, update[[len + 1]], {All, diam}]; 
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch]
]
```

but again, same error. I noticed that while `bFill[[1]]` contained the values I expected, `bFill[[2]]` contained more values (43 vs the 15 it should have had) and missed some that values I would have expected it to pick up. SO something about how this is being written isn't translating correctly when I try to put it into a `While` loop.

Comment: The condition in the first argument of `While` is checked _before_ the second argument is executed. So the loop does not start if `update` is undefined or `{}`. It should suffice to define `update={1}` before the loop.

Comment: "Pro" tip: doing `AppendTo` in a loop in Mathematica is doomed to be slow when the list you accumulate becomes long... Either pre-allocate the list first using e.g. `ConstantArray` and then modify elements, or better, use `Table`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `update` and `diam` are defined outside of the `While` loop, so I don't understand why this would be a problem or why `update` would be redefined as `update={1}` -  I need the data that is initially stored in `update`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thanks for the comment. I was thinking of something like that, but the problem is I do not know a priori how long each branch will be (though I they do have a max length of 200, in this case) or how many branches there will end up being (can't guess without manually checking a step how many this will be). I am trying to use this specific time step where I know what the results will be to help myself in the coding. This is just one time step in roughly a million other time steps that I will be applying this to, so I want to leave this as "flexible" as possible, as it were.

Comment: In the case where the number of elements are not/cannot be known in advance, the idiomatic way is to use `Reap` + `Sow`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I've used `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` when using `Module` to make functions before, but admit I don't immediately see the applicability here.

Comment: Replace `AppendTo` inside the `While` by `Sow`, and wrap the whole thing in a `Reap` on the outside.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I tried the `update={1}` suggestion and `bFill` just returned back empty, which is what I was expecting to happen, but thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: By the way, another performance thing: consider using `Complement` instead of `DeleteCases` with `Alternatives @@ branch`! It works basically like a set complement. :)

Comment: Are the `list[[len + 1]]`'s in the first example supposed to be `update[[len + 1]]`s?

Comment: Another note: you can get `len` simply by mapping `Length` over `bfill`, via `Length /@ bfill`, and then applying `Total` To the result. Alternatively, you could also get `len` by simply flattening the first level and then taking the length, via `Length[Flatten[bfill,1]]`.

Comment: @thorimur Yes, I just noticed that. I have a copy of `update` called `list` that I don't mess with at all, and that was actually the key to getting this to work - I realised when I finally rewrote this as a `For` loop instead! Also, thank you for the `len` and `Compliment` suggestions, I will take these into account!!

Comment: Ah, nice! I typed this up into an answer, but didn't see that in the meantime you had answered it yourself  anyway, there it is!

Comment: Also, btw, just so you're able to find the function: it's `Complement`, not `Compliment`! :) Also, sorry, I think I misunderstood the intended problem in my answer: I assumed you wanted *disjoint* clusters, as opposed to a cluster for each element!

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple small improvements, first!

- `DeleteCases[list1, Alternatives @@ list2]` is, if `list2` is full of literals and not pattern objects, as is the case here, the same as `Complement[list1, list2]`, which gives all those elements of `list1` not in `list2`.
- Instead of accessing a whole table and recalculating `len` from scratch each time we pass through the while loop, we can just tack on the length of the latest `branch` each time we compute `branch`, as `len += Length[branch]`. (And we start with a nice `len = 0` before entering the loop.)
- Instead of calculating the length of `update` in the while loop check each time, you can just check if it's the empty list: `update != {}`. This would only matter if `update` were absolutely enormous, though (and/or we were going through many, many times).
- Instead of using `AppendTo`, it's quicker to `Sow` and `Reap`—or to build up things by nesting, like `v = {newstuff, v}` and flatten later (if we don't care about list structure, but we do).

Otherwise, your loop is basically right! But you've made one error: each time you pass through the loop, you delete everything you don't want anymore from `update`. So you don't want the `len + 1`'th element of `update`—you want the first! That is, you want `Nearest[update, First[update], {All, diam}]`.

So, it turns out it's not a loop problem, it's a structure problem; and it turns out we don't even actually need to calculate the length of `bfill` anymore.

Putting it together with `Reap` and `Sow` we'd have

```
Reap[
 While[
  update != {}, 
  branch = Nearest[update, First[update], {All, diam}]; 
  Sow[branch];
  update = Complement[update, branch];
 ]
]
```

The output of `Reap` is weird: used like this, it's a list `{output, {{SowedElements}} }`. Here the output is `Null` since we end with a `;`. So we'd need to actually use `First@Last@Reap[...]` or something equivalent.

I'm personally curious if there's a way to implement this loop with *only* `Sow` and `Reap` while `Scan`ning through the list (no `While` loop), using different tags for each cluster (that's why there's the extra list enclosure in the output of `Reap`), and if it's faster or slower!

Update: I think I might have misunderstood the intended output—I assumed you wanted disjoint clusters, as opposed to a cluster for each element. If you want a cluster for each element, there's a really slick way of doing it by simply mapping the "cluster-creating function" over the entire list of data:

```
Nearest[update, #, {All,diam}] & /@ update
```

That would be the entire thing! :)

Comment: This is an interesting answer, and I thank you for giving improvement suggestions! I'll definitely be incorporating them . I did notice while comparing that the two methods seem to give slightly different results for the clusters, and I also noticed that it seems to start at the top cluster, then go to the bottom and work its way up? Pretty interesting! For my own bookkeeping purposes, I need it that in the list it always goes cluster 1, 2, ..., n. But really thank you for taking the time to type this up, I never would have come up with something so neat, and I appreciate the improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but this should get you started I think. Given your data, outputs 5 groups, first 4 match your example, I assume one was left off there since you state 5 elsewhere.

```
pos = 1;
tmp = {};
res2 = Reap[
   While[pos < Length@update, 
     Sow[tmp = 
       Cases[update[[pos ;;]], x_ /; update[[pos]] - x <= diam]];
     pos += (Length@tmp);];][[2, 1]];

Short/@res2
```

> {{215.747,215.238,213.231,<<41>>,208.3,208.169,208.143},{137.806,137.792,137.68,<<9>>,131.253,124.246,123.571},{123.543,123.357,123.277,<<32>>,118.481,117.876,117.574},{-165.322,-165.584,<<41>>,-178.261,-178.486},
> {-210.531,-211.429,-211.476,<<50>>,-218.343,-224.348}}

Comment: Thank you for this comment! I'll admit that it is a bit difficult for me to parse going through it step by step... I realised where I was going on when I was rewriting the code using `For` loop instead in addition to another comment, and will be answering with my `For` and `While` loop work-arounds, just in case it helps anyone (doubtful, but you never know...!)

Answer (score 2):

Here's where I went wrong: so I am deleting elements from `update` while I *also* have a copy of `update` called `list` - I do nothing to this list. So I started rewriting the code using a `For` loop and I ended up having to put in this `Break[]`, otherwise it would add a nonsense list to the list of lists (or I could always just delete the last element?) Regardless, the `For` loop:

```
list = update;
bFill = branch = uL = {};
len = 0;

For[i = 1, i <= 200, i += len;
branch = Nearest[update, list[[i]], {All, diam}];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
len = Length@branch;
AppendTo[uL, Length@update];
If[Last@uL == 0, Break[]]
]
```

Then, when I realised I needed to use `list` in the `For` loop in addition to @thorimur's comments, I was able to write the `While` loop like so:

```
list = update;
bFill = branch = uL = {};
len = 0;

While[Length@update > 0, 
len = Total[Table[Length@bFill[[i]], {i, Length@bFill}]];
branch = Nearest[update, list[[len + 1]], {All, diam}];
AppendTo[bFill, branch];
update = DeleteCases[update, Alternatives @@ branch]]
```

I'll be implementing @thorimur's comments re using `Compliment` and `Length[Flatten[bfill,1]]`.

Thanks a lot everybody for suggestions and comments, this was really driving me nuts!